# Android database query gets nullpointer

Tags: android, database, sqlite, pointers, null

I loaded a Database from my SD Card via

```
SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbfile, null);
```

I created the select String

```
String select = "Column1 like " + "'%Incoming%'" + " and " + "Column2 not like " + "'%null%'";
```

Then i want to select the matching data with the cursor

```
Cursor curs = db.query(true, TABLE1, new String[]{COLUMN1}, select, null, null, null, COLUMN2 + " DESC", null);
```

But now, the Cursor line throws a Nullpointer and i have no idea why.
My loaded database has 6 columns,  i took the correct column names but it still throws an exception.

Comment: i tested the query via SQLiteMan and i got results. It seems like the access to the database doesnt work... any help?

Comment: didnt use the SQLiteHelper class. i changed the database in it and used the helper and...it worked!